# Docker connection refused between containers after compose

Tags: .net, azure, docker, microservices

We are using a docker compose file to release our .NET based microservice architecture. However since we introduced env files for the services, releases never go according to what they used to.
These env files only contain secrets/keys/connstrings no critical data, that is required for running.

The docker compose task, portainer and logs show no error or anything out of the ordinary, but the main entry point container can't reach a few of them, giving no timeout or unknown host, but a Connection Refused response immediately. We stop a "missing" container, wait 10 seconds, start the container and it magically works. Not all container communication is faulty, but usually the same ones after every release.

The containers are in a named stack and automatically added to the default network of the stack.
The machine in question is an on-premise linux system in Hyper-V, running Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker version is 20.10.17.

Docker compose file snippet, launched via command `docker-compose -p demo up -d --build`

```
services:
  service1:
    image: service1
    hostname: service1.hostname
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./service1.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - service1.env

  service2:
    image: service2
    hostname: service2.hostname
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./service2.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 15443:443
    env_file:
      - service2.env
```

The services are assigned a hostname each in the compose file and they are communicating using that hostname. These are 2 of the service examples from the docker compose file, the containers use the https://service1.hostname pattern to communicate.

Azure is only marked in the labels, because it is deployed via an azure release pipeline, but with our self-hosted agent, so I'm not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: Are you absolute certain that  this is related to the `.env` files, i.e. does everything work as expected when you replace the `env_file`-section with, for example, an `environment`-section or supply the needed variables in another way? Or did you, for example, remove a `depends_on`-section when adding the `env_file`-section?

Comment: The functionality of the containers are as expected, reaching every database, once running. Looking at the PR, the `depends_on` sections are untouched and intact, only the env variables part changed. Before the env files we used an `environment` section with some values there, but I am unsure why one works and the other one not really, the whole point of the env files was to inject the secret values and not build into the docker image with appsettings.json.

Comment: At this point, this very much sounds like a case for the azure support